# How can I have two outState statements in my onSaveInstanceState method in Android?

Tags: android, sql, error-handling

i have a problem with my onSaveInstanceState method in my android app. I have got two SQL databases hooked up, the RemindersDbAdapter and the ImageAdapter.

Consequently I ended up with this in my main activity:

```
private Long mRowId;
private Long mImageRowId;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    outState.putLong(ImageAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mImageRowId);
}
```

The problem is that this code crashes. Can someone give me a tip to fix this problem??

Comment: Post you're stacktrace as an edit will help us help you :)

Comment: Are you sure that `mRowId` and `mImageRowId` are not `null` when `onSaveInstanceState()` gets called?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help with stacktrace provided :)

Don't know if it matters, but try calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` **after** you put your longs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that problem is in `onSaveInstanceState()`, then most likely either `mRowId` or `mImageRowId` is `null`:

```
private static final Long DEF_ROW_ID = 0L;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId != null ? mRowId : DEF_ROW_ID);
    outState.putLong(ImageAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mImageRowId != null ? mImageRowId : DEF_ROW_ID);
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much, but I think my problem is related with something different. The thing is, that I can´t store the path of an image in my sql database.